# Php fetching and echoing in HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

```
<?php  
    include_once 'config.php';  

    $query = $config -> prepare("SELECT `edit`, `user_banned`, `ban_reason`, `ban_time`, `user_banner`, `ban_timestamp` FROM `samp_ban` ORDER BY `edit` ASC LIMIT 10");  
    if($query -> execute())  
    {  
        $query_results = $query->fetchAll();
         if($ban_time == 0) { $query_result["ban_time"] = "Permanent"; } 

    }  
?>
```

code edidetcode edidetcode edidetcode edidet

ERROR: Undefined variable: ban_time

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading in

Comment: In your while loop where you fetch, echo a row with all surrounding HTML tags (`<div class="row">`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to output same variables on both rows. As a result you get two rows with same results. You have to store rows from database to array and then make a for loop to output your html with data from that array.

PHP code

```
<?php  
    include_once 'config.php';  

    $query = $config -> prepare("SELECT `Username`, `Headshots`, `ForumName` FROM `users` ORDER BY `Headshots` DESC LIMIT 10");  

    if($query -> execute())  
    {  
        $query_results = $query->fetchAll();
    }  
?>
```

HTML code

```
<div class="limiter">

    <div class="container-table100">
        <div class="wrap-table100">
            <div class="table">

                <div class="row header">
                    <div class="cell">
                        Nickname
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        Headshots
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        Forum Name
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php foreach( $query_results as $query_result ) { ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                        <?php echo $query_result["Username"]; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Headshots">
                        <?php echo $query_result["Headshots"]; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell" data-title="Forum Title">
                        <?php echo $query_result["ForumName"]; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: I have a question, I want to add.    if($Username == 0) {
   $ban_time = "Yes";
  } else if($Username == 1) {
   $Username= "no";
    }

Comment: @NewbieHTML, I would also suggest to always consider security when outputting text to HTML. `<?php echo $query_result["Username"]; ?>` is dangerous if Username is allowed to contain special characters used in HTML markup or javascript. In such cases as this I would really recommend using `htmlspecialchars()`: `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($query_result["Username"]); ?>`. That way if for example username is `<B>ill` you will see the real user name instead of bold `ill`.

Comment: Well, thank you, but it gives me an error. Cannot use object of type PDOStatement as array

Comment: You probably used `$query` variable instead of `$query_result`. In my suggested code `$query` is PDOStatement, `$query_results` is an array of rows (associative arrays) and `$query_result` is an associative array with row data (Username, Headshots, ForumName). Make sure you use correct variables :)

Comment: You should keep original question and ask a new question if you need further assistance with your changing code. Currently your issue is that there is no `$ban_time` variable. You should put your conditional code in the for loop and use `$query_result` variable. Put `<?php if($query_result["ban_time"] == 0) { $query_result["ban_time"] = "Permanent"; } ?>` after `<?php foreach( $query_results as $query_result ) { ?>`. `$query_result` is available ONLY in the for loop that iterates through `$query_results` array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to combine and html and php for getting all data from query

```
if($row_count)  
        {  
            while($query_result = $query -> fetch()){  
                 $Username = $query_result['Username']; 
                 $Headshots = $query_result['Headshots']; 
                 $ForumName = $query_result['ForumName'] ; 
                 ?>
                 <div class="row">
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">
                                <?php echo $Username ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Headshots">
                                <?php echo $Headshots ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="cell" data-title="Forum Title">
                                <?php echo $ForumName ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 <?php
                }
        }
```

Comment: syntax error, unexpected '<'

I removed all cell div's and added yours, only 1, but error is shown

Comment: edit the question and put what you have tried and which line you are getting error

Comment: Done @Vishnu Bhadoriya

Comment: you are not closing php tag ?> add the ?> @ line 72

Comment: Thank you for your help and time !

Answer (score 0):

You need to change

```
<?php  
    include_once 'config.php';  

    $query = $config -> prepare("SELECT `Username`, `Headshots`, `ForumName` FROM `users` ORDER BY `Headshots` DESC LIMIT 10");  

    if($query -> execute())  
    {  
        $row_count = $query -> rowCount();  

        if($row_count)  
        {  
            while($query_result = $query -> fetch())  
                 $Username = $query_result['Username']; 
                 $Headshots = $query_result['Headshots']; 
                 $ForumName = $query_result['ForumName'] ; 
        }  
    }  
?>
```

into

```
<?php  
    include_once 'config.php';  

    $query = $config -> prepare("SELECT `Username`, `Headshots`, `ForumName` FROM `users` ORDER BY `Headshots` DESC LIMIT 10");  

    if($query -> execute())  
    {  
        $row_count = $query -> rowCount();  

        if($row_count)  
        {  
            while($query_result = $query -> fetch()) 
            { 
                 $Username = $query_result['Username']; 
                 $Headshots = $query_result['Headshots']; 
                 $ForumName = $query_result['ForumName'] ; 
                 echo '<div class="row">';
                        echo '<div class="cell" data-title="Full Name">';
                             echo $Username;
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="cell" data-title="Headshots">';
                            echo $Headshots;
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '<div class="cell" data-title="Forum Title">';
                            echo $ForumName;
                        echo '</div>';
                     echo '</div>';
            }
        }  
    }  
?>
```

You forgot the { }  arround the while loop

Comment: Oh lol, yeah. Thank you.  But now it remains only one problem, I need to echo 9 more user's data, way made by me is only for 1 user,  in the initial script was for all 10 users but they were shown only in 1 row.